# Conditional expression in ternary operator in C

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i;
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        (i % 2) ? printf("%d is odd\n", i) : printf("%d is even\n", i);
  }
}
```

Result

```
1 is odd
2 is even
3 is odd
4 is even
5 is odd
6 is even
7 is odd
8 is even
9 is odd
10 is even
```

In the above C program, why it still works fine even though the conditional expression only states `i%2` and not `i%2!=0` ?

Comment: `i%2` is a scalar value expression. it is implicitly considerable for true (non-zero) or false (zero) in an expression context like yours.

Comment: `printf ("%d is %s\n", i, i % 2 ? "odd" : "even")` works as well `:)`

Comment: Or, `static const char *msg[] = {"even","odd"};` and within your loop, you do something like `printf("%d is %s\n", i, msg[i%2]);` , but now we're getting way off the charter of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, integers can be used in a Boolean context, and zero represents false while non-zero represents true.

That's why your code works. The expression `num % 2` will be 0 (the single false value) for an even number and 1 (one of the many possible true values) for an odd number.

The following expressions would all work for detecting an odd number:

```
num % 2
(num % 2) != 0
((num % 2) != 0) != 0
... and so on, ad untilyougetboredum (like 'ad infinitum' but with limits).
```

Having said that, I don't really consider it a good *idea* to do it this way, code should express *intent* as much as possible and the intent here should be to choose the path of execution based on a comparison. That means, if you're looking for an odd number, you should use something like `(num % 2) == 1`.

You also don't need a separate `printf` call in *each* of those code paths:

```
printf("%d is %s\n", num, ((num % 2) == 1) ? "odd" : "even");
```

---

You'll notice I've also used `num` instead of `i`. This is simply a style thing of mine, related to the afore-mentioned intent. If the variable is only used as an index, I'm happy to use the `i`-type variables<sup>(a)</sup> but, the second it gains a semantic property (like a number being checked for oddity), I tend to use more descriptive names.

I have no *issue* with people using simple variable names, I just prefer more descriptive ones in my own code.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Actually, I'd probably use `idx` in that case but that's being *too* CDO<sup>(b)</sup>, even for me :-)

---

<sup>(b)</sup> OCD but in the right order :-)

Answer (score -1):

C doesn't have a dedicated *boolean* type. It uses int value as boolean. That is 0 is considered `false` and any non zero value is treated as `true`. 
Try printing some conditions

```
printf("%d",5==5);
printf("%d",1>3);
```

This will output
1 and 0.

C always uses 1 to denote `true`. But any other non-zero value would work as well when using in conditions.

```
if(6+1)
    printf("TRUE");
```

Will print TRUE.

This is also the reason we can use this form of while loop:

```
int i= 10;
while(i--){
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Will print `9876543210`. Notice it stops when i becomes 0, which is `false`.

Now back to the question, `i%2` would always result in either 0 or 1. In case of 1(true) the first statement is run while in case of 0 (false) the second statement is run.

Comment: It does have a dedicated boolean type, `_Bool`

Comment: Yes. But it still resolves to an integer ( 0 or 1). It doesn't have dedicated boolean type like in some other languages like Java that is different from mere int.

Comment: no, it does have a dedicated Boolean type like other languages